# When I try to upgrade my Spring Framework version, the whole projects have problems

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I am currently using Spring Framework version 4.1.6.RELEASE. When I try to upgrade its version to 4.2.4.RELEASE, my projects is in trouble.

Upgrading version to 4.1.7 - 4.2.3 is totally fine, but I need above 4.2.4 version. Can anyone tell me what is wrong here?

Here is my entire pom.xml.
And now I am also having this problem while I am testing my api with jUnit.

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.isu</groupId>
    <artifactId>ifm</artifactId>
    <name>IfMobileHrAdapterService</name>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <version>1.0.0-BUILD-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <properties>
        <!-- Generic properties -->
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>

        <!-- Spring -->
        <springframework.version>4.2.5.RELEASE</springframework.version>
        <springframework.jpa.version>1.8.0.RELEASE</springframework.jpa.version>
        <springframework.ldap.version>2.0.3.RELEASE</springframework.ldap.version>

        <!-- Mysql -->
        <db.version>5.1.35</db.version>

        <!-- Hibernate / JPA -->
        <hibernate.version>4.3.8.Final</hibernate.version>
        <hibernate.validator.version>5.1.3.Final</hibernate.validator.version>
        <hibernate.core.version>4.3.8.Final</hibernate.core.version>

        <org.aspectj-version>1.8.5</org.aspectj-version>
        <!-- Logging -->
        <org.slf4j-version>1.6.6</org.slf4j-version>

        <!-- Test -->
        <junit.version>4.11</junit.version>

    </properties>

    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>thirdparty</id>
            <url>http://hatch.pearbranch.com:8081/content/repositories/thirdparty</url>
        </repository>
    </repositories>


    <dependencies>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.tika/tika-core -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.tika</groupId>
            <artifactId>tika-core</artifactId>
            <version>1.8</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.tika/tika -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.tika</groupId>
            <artifactId>tika</artifactId>
            <version>1.8</version>
            <type>pom</type>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.commons/commons-lang3 -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>
            <version>3.3.2</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Oracle -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>oracle</groupId>
            <artifactId>OracleDriver</artifactId>
            <version>11.2.0.1.0</version>
            <scope>system</scope>
            <systemPath>${basedir}/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/lib/ojdbc6.jar</systemPath>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>log4sql</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4sql</artifactId>
            <version>1.0</version>
            <scope>system</scope>
            <systemPath>${basedir}/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/lib/log4sql.jar</systemPath>
        </dependency>


        <!-- JSON -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.json</groupId>
            <artifactId>json</artifactId>
            <version>20141113</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.validation</groupId>
            <artifactId>validation-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.0.GA</version>
        </dependency>


        <!-- Spring -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-beans</artifactId>
            <version>${springframework.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-jdbc</artifactId>
            <version>${springframework.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
            <version>${springframework.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-test</artifactId>
            <version>${springframework.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
            <version>${springframework.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context-support</artifactId>
            <version>${springframework.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
            <version>${springframework.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-tx</artifactId>
            <version>${springframework.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
            <version>${springframework.version}</version>
            <exclusions>
                <!-- Exclude Commons Logging in favor of SLF4j -->
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
                    <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>




        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/log4j/apache-log4j-extras -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>apache-log4j-extras</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.17</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>${junit.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-beans</artifactId>
            <version>${springframework.version}</version>
        </dependency>


    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <!-- <sourceDirectory>src</sourceDirectory> -->
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.5.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.8</source>
                    <target>1.8</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.6</version>
                <configuration>
                    <warSourceDirectory>WebContent</warSourceDirectory>
                    <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

```
PS D:\Workspace\SpringToolSuiteProjects\ifMobileApiUnitTest> mvn clean package
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[WARNING]
[WARNING] Some problems were encountered while building the effective model for com.isu:ifm:war:1.0.0-BUILD-SNAPSHOT
[WARNING] 'dependencies.dependency.systemPath' for oracle:OracleDriver:jar should not point at files within the project directory, ${basedir}/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/lib/ojdbc6.jar will be unresolvable by dependent projects @ line 76, column 16
[WARNING] 'dependencies.dependency.systemPath' for log4sql:log4sql:jar should not point at files within the project directory, ${basedir}/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/lib/log4sql.jar will be unresolvable by dependent projects @ line 84, column 16
[WARNING] 'dependencies.dependency.(groupId:artifactId:type:classifier)' must be unique: org.springframework:spring-beans:jar -> duplicate declaration of version ${springframework.version} @ line 178, column 15
[WARNING]
[WARNING] It is highly recommended to fix these problems because they threaten the stability of your build.
[WARNING]
[WARNING] For this reason, future Maven versions might no longer support building such malformed projects.
[WARNING]
[INFO]
[INFO] ----------------------------< com.isu:ifm >-----------------------------
[INFO] Building IfMobileHrAdapterService 1.0.0-BUILD-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] --------------------------------[ war ]---------------------------------
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-clean-plugin:2.5:clean (default-clean) @ ifm ---
[INFO] Deleting D:\Workspace\SpringToolSuiteProjects\ifMobileApiUnitTest\target
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.6:resources (default-resources) @ ifm ---
[INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
[INFO] Copying 1 resource
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.5.1:compile (default-compile) @ ifm ---
[INFO] Changes detected - recompiling the module!
[INFO] Compiling 4 source files to D:\Workspace\SpringToolSuiteProjects\ifMobileApiUnitTest\target\classes
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] COMPILATION ERROR :
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] /D:/Workspace/SpringToolSuiteProjects/ifMobileApiUnitTest/src/main/java/com/isu/ifm/testcase/LoginControllerTest.java:[4,17] package org.junit does not exist
[ERROR] /D:/Workspace/SpringToolSuiteProjects/ifMobileApiUnitTest/src/main/java/com/isu/ifm/testcase/LoginControllerTest.java:[5,17] package org.junit does not exist
[ERROR] /D:/Workspace/SpringToolSuiteProjects/ifMobileApiUnitTest/src/main/java/com/isu/ifm/testcase/LoginControllerTest.java:[6,24] package org.junit.runner does not exist
[ERROR] /D:/Workspace/SpringToolSuiteProjects/ifMobileApiUnitTest/src/main/java/com/isu/ifm/testcase/LoginControllerTest.java:[7,19] package org.mockito does not exist
[ERROR] /D:/Workspace/SpringToolSuiteProjects/ifMobileApiUnitTest/src/main/java/com/isu/ifm/testcase/LoginControllerTest.java:[8,19] package org.mockito does not exist
[ERROR] /D:/Workspace/SpringToolSuiteProjects/ifMobileApiUnitTest/src/main/java/com/isu/ifm/testcase/LoginControllerTest.java:[9,19] package org.mockito does not exist
[ERROR] /D:/Workspace/SpringToolSuiteProjects/ifMobileApiUnitTest/src/main/java/com/isu/ifm/testcase/LoginControllerTest.java:[18,30] package com.isu.ifm.hr.control does not exist
[ERROR] /D:/Workspace/SpringToolSuiteProjects/ifMobileApiUnitTest/src/main/java/com/isu/ifm/testcase/LoginControllerTest.java:[19,30] package com.isu.ifm.hr.service does not exist
[ERROR] /D:/Workspace/SpringToolSuiteProjects/ifMobileApiUnitTest/src/main/java/com/isu/ifm/testcase/LoginControllerTest.java:[21,2] cannot find symbol
  symbol: class RunWith
[ERROR] /D:/Workspace/SpringToolSuiteProjects/ifMobileApiUnitTest/src/main/java/com/isu/ifm/testcase/LoginControllerTest.java:[26,23] cannot find symbol
  symbol:   class LoginService
  location: class com.isu.ifm.testcase.LoginControllerTest
[ERROR] /D:/Workspace/SpringToolSuiteProjects/ifMobileApiUnitTest/src/main/java/com/isu/ifm/testcase/LoginControllerTest.java:[27,30] cannot find symbol
  symbol:   class LoginController
  location: class com.isu.ifm.testcase.LoginControllerTest
[ERROR] /D:/Workspace/SpringToolSuiteProjects/ifMobileApiUnitTest/src/main/java/com/isu/ifm/testcase/SalaryControllerTest.java:[4,17] package org.junit does not exist
[ERROR] /D:/Workspace/SpringToolSuiteProjects/ifMobileApiUnitTest/src/main/java/com/isu/ifm/testcase/SalaryControllerTest.java:[5,17] package org.junit does not exist
[ERROR] /D:/Workspace/SpringToolSuiteProjects/ifMobileApiUnitTest/src/main/java/com/isu/ifm/testcase/SalaryControllerTest.java:[6,24] package org.junit.runner does not exist
[ERROR] /D:/Workspace/SpringToolSuiteProjects/ifMobileApiUnitTest/src/main/java/com/isu/ifm/testcase/SalaryControllerTest.java:[14,30] package com.isu.ifm.hr.control does not exist
[ERROR] /D:/Workspace/SpringToolSuiteProjects/ifMobileApiUnitTest/src/main/java/com/isu/ifm/testcase/SalaryControllerTest.java:[16,2] cannot find symbol
  symbol: class RunWith
[ERROR] /D:/Workspace/SpringToolSuiteProjects/ifMobileApiUnitTest/src/main/java/com/isu/ifm/testcase/SalaryControllerTest.java:[23,9] cannot find symbol
  symbol:   class SalaryController
  location: class com.isu.ifm.testcase.SalaryControllerTest
[ERROR] /D:/Workspace/SpringToolSuiteProjects/ifMobileApiUnitTest/src/main/java/com/isu/ifm/testcase/EDocumentControllerTest.java:[4,17] package org.junit does not exist
[ERROR] /D:/Workspace/SpringToolSuiteProjects/ifMobileApiUnitTest/src/main/java/com/isu/ifm/testcase/EDocumentControllerTest.java:[6,24] package org.junit.runner does not exist
[ERROR] /D:/Workspace/SpringToolSuiteProjects/ifMobileApiUnitTest/src/main/java/com/isu/ifm/testcase/EDocumentControllerTest.java:[14,30] package com.isu.ifm.hr.control does not exist
[ERROR] /D:/Workspace/SpringToolSuiteProjects/ifMobileApiUnitTest/src/main/java/com/isu/ifm/testcase/EDocumentControllerTest.java:[16,2] cannot find symbol
  symbol: class RunWith
[ERROR] /D:/Workspace/SpringToolSuiteProjects/ifMobileApiUnitTest/src/main/java/com/isu/ifm/testcase/EDocumentControllerTest.java:[23,9] cannot find symbol
  symbol:   class EDocumentController
  location: class com.isu.ifm.testcase.EDocumentControllerTest
[ERROR] /D:/Workspace/SpringToolSuiteProjects/ifMobileApiUnitTest/src/main/java/com/isu/ifm/testcase/LoginControllerTest.java:[26,10] cannot find symbol
  symbol:   class Mock
  location: class com.isu.ifm.testcase.LoginControllerTest
[ERROR] /D:/Workspace/SpringToolSuiteProjects/ifMobileApiUnitTest/src/main/java/com/isu/ifm/testcase/LoginControllerTest.java:[27,10] cannot find symbol
  symbol:   class InjectMocks
  location: class com.isu.ifm.testcase.LoginControllerTest
[ERROR] /D:/Workspace/SpringToolSuiteProjects/ifMobileApiUnitTest/src/main/java/com/isu/ifm/testcase/LoginControllerTest.java:[34,6] cannot find symbol
  symbol:   class Before
  location: class com.isu.ifm.testcase.LoginControllerTest
[ERROR] /D:/Workspace/SpringToolSuiteProjects/ifMobileApiUnitTest/src/main/java/com/isu/ifm/testcase/LoginControllerTest.java:[40,6] cannot find symbol
  symbol:   class Test
  location: class com.isu.ifm.testcase.LoginControllerTest
[ERROR] /D:/Workspace/SpringToolSuiteProjects/ifMobileApiUnitTest/src/main/java/com/isu/ifm/testcase/SalaryControllerTest.java:[25,6] cannot find symbol
  symbol:   class Before
  location: class com.isu.ifm.testcase.SalaryControllerTest
[ERROR] /D:/Workspace/SpringToolSuiteProjects/ifMobileApiUnitTest/src/main/java/com/isu/ifm/testcase/SalaryControllerTest.java:[30,6] cannot find symbol
  symbol:   class Test
  location: class com.isu.ifm.testcase.SalaryControllerTest
[ERROR] /D:/Workspace/SpringToolSuiteProjects/ifMobileApiUnitTest/src/main/java/com/isu/ifm/testcase/EDocumentControllerTest.java:[25,6] cannot find symbol
  symbol:   class Before
  location: class com.isu.ifm.testcase.EDocumentControllerTest
[ERROR] /D:/Workspace/SpringToolSuiteProjects/ifMobileApiUnitTest/src/main/java/com/isu/ifm/testcase/EDocumentControllerTest.java:[30,6] cannot find symbol
  symbol:   class Test
  location: class com.isu.ifm.testcase.EDocumentControllerTest
[ERROR] /D:/Workspace/SpringToolSuiteProjects/ifMobileApiUnitTest/src/main/java/com/isu/ifm/testcase/LoginControllerTest.java:[36,9] cannot find symbol
  symbol:   variable MockitoAnnotations
  location: class com.isu.ifm.testcase.LoginControllerTest
[ERROR] /D:/Workspace/SpringToolSuiteProjects/ifMobileApiUnitTest/src/main/java/com/isu/ifm/testcase/SalaryControllerTest.java:[23,49] cannot find symbol
  symbol:   class SalaryController
  location: class com.isu.ifm.testcase.SalaryControllerTest
[ERROR] /D:/Workspace/SpringToolSuiteProjects/ifMobileApiUnitTest/src/main/java/com/isu/ifm/testcase/EDocumentControllerTest.java:[23,55] cannot find symbol
  symbol:   class EDocumentController
  location: class com.isu.ifm.testcase.EDocumentControllerTest
[INFO] 33 errors
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 3.814 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2018-11-02T18:07:26+09:00
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.5.1:compile (default-compile) on project ifm: Compilation failure: Compilation failure:
[ERROR] /D:/Workspace/SpringToolSuiteProjects/ifMobileApiUnitTest/src/main/java/com/isu/ifm/testcase/LoginControllerTest.java:[4,17] package org.junit does not exist
[ERROR] /D:/Workspace/SpringToolSuiteProjects/ifMobileApiUnitTest/src/main/java/com/isu/ifm/testcase/LoginControllerTest.java:[5,17] package org.junit does not exist
[ERROR] /D:/Workspace/SpringToolSuiteProjects/ifMobileApiUnitTest/src/main/java/com/isu/ifm/testcase/LoginControllerTest.java:[6,24] package org.junit.runner does not exist
[ERROR] /D:/Workspace/SpringToolSuiteProjects/ifMobileApiUnitTest/src/main/java/com/isu/ifm/testcase/LoginControllerTest.java:[7,19] package org.mockito does not exist
[ERROR] /D:/Workspace/SpringToolSuiteProjects/ifMobileApiUnitTest/src/main/java/com/isu/ifm/testcase/LoginControllerTest.java:[8,19] package org.mockito does not exist
[ERROR] /D:/Workspace/SpringToolSuiteProjects/ifMobileApiUnitTest/src/main/java/com/isu/ifm/testcase/LoginControllerTest.java:[9,19] package org.mockito does not exist
[ERROR] /D:/Workspace/SpringToolSuiteProjects/ifMobileApiUnitTest/src/main/java/com/isu/ifm/testcase/LoginControllerTest.java:[18,30] package com.isu.ifm.hr.control does not exist
[ERROR] /D:/Workspace/SpringToolSuiteProjects/ifMobileApiUnitTest/src/main/java/com/isu/ifm/testcase/LoginControllerTest.java:[19,30] package com.isu.ifm.hr.service does not exist
[ERROR] /D:/Workspace/SpringToolSuiteProjects/ifMobileApiUnitTest/src/main/java/com/isu/ifm/testcase/LoginControllerTest.java:[21,2] cannot find symbol
[ERROR]   symbol: class RunWith
[ERROR] /D:/Workspace/SpringToolSuiteProjects/ifMobileApiUnitTest/src/main/java/com/isu/ifm/testcase/LoginControllerTest.java:[26,23] cannot find symbol
[ERROR]   symbol:   class LoginService
[ERROR]   location: class com.isu.ifm.testcase.LoginControllerTest
[ERROR] /D:/Workspace/SpringToolSuiteProjects/ifMobileApiUnitTest/src/main/java/com/isu/ifm/testcase/LoginControllerTest.java:[27,30] cannot find symbol
[ERROR]   symbol:   class LoginController
[ERROR]   location: class com.isu.ifm.testcase.LoginControllerTest
[ERROR] /D:/Workspace/SpringToolSuiteProjects/ifMobileApiUnitTest/src/main/java/com/isu/ifm/testcase/SalaryControllerTest.java:[4,17] package org.junit does not exist
[ERROR] /D:/Workspace/SpringToolSuiteProjects/ifMobileApiUnitTest/src/main/java/com/isu/ifm/testcase/SalaryControllerTest.java:[5,17] package org.junit does not exist
[ERROR] /D:/Workspace/SpringToolSuiteProjects/ifMobileApiUnitTest/src/main/java/com/isu/ifm/testcase/SalaryControllerTest.java:[6,24] package org.junit.runner does not exist
[ERROR] /D:/Workspace/SpringToolSuiteProjects/ifMobileApiUnitTest/src/main/java/com/isu/ifm/testcase/SalaryControllerTest.java:[14,30] package com.isu.ifm.hr.control does not exist
[ERROR] /D:/Workspace/SpringToolSuiteProjects/ifMobileApiUnitTest/src/main/java/com/isu/ifm/testcase/SalaryControllerTest.java:[16,2] cannot find symbol
[ERROR]   symbol: class RunWith
[ERROR] /D:/Workspace/SpringToolSuiteProjects/ifMobileApiUnitTest/src/main/java/com/isu/ifm/testcase/SalaryControllerTest.java:[23,9] cannot find symbol
[ERROR]   symbol:   class SalaryController
[ERROR]   location: class com.isu.ifm.testcase.SalaryControllerTest
[ERROR] /D:/Workspace/SpringToolSuiteProjects/ifMobileApiUnitTest/src/main/java/com/isu/ifm/testcase/EDocumentControllerTest.java:[4,17] package org.junit does not exist
[ERROR] /D:/Workspace/SpringToolSuiteProjects/ifMobileApiUnitTest/src/main/java/com/isu/ifm/testcase/EDocumentControllerTest.java:[6,24] package org.junit.runner does not exist
[ERROR] /D:/Workspace/SpringToolSuiteProjects/ifMobileApiUnitTest/src/main/java/com/isu/ifm/testcase/EDocumentControllerTest.java:[14,30] package com.isu.ifm.hr.control does not exist
[ERROR] /D:/Workspace/SpringToolSuiteProjects/ifMobileApiUnitTest/src/main/java/com/isu/ifm/testcase/EDocumentControllerTest.java:[16,2] cannot find symbol
[ERROR]   symbol: class RunWith
[ERROR] /D:/Workspace/SpringToolSuiteProjects/ifMobileApiUnitTest/src/main/java/com/isu/ifm/testcase/EDocumentControllerTest.java:[23,9] cannot find symbol
[ERROR]   symbol:   class EDocumentController
[ERROR]   location: class com.isu.ifm.testcase.EDocumentControllerTest
[ERROR] /D:/Workspace/SpringToolSuiteProjects/ifMobileApiUnitTest/src/main/java/com/isu/ifm/testcase/LoginControllerTest.java:[26,10] cannot find symbol
[ERROR]   symbol:   class Mock
[ERROR]   location: class com.isu.ifm.testcase.LoginControllerTest
[ERROR] /D:/Workspace/SpringToolSuiteProjects/ifMobileApiUnitTest/src/main/java/com/isu/ifm/testcase/LoginControllerTest.java:[27,10] cannot find symbol
[ERROR]   symbol:   class InjectMocks
[ERROR]   location: class com.isu.ifm.testcase.LoginControllerTest
[ERROR] /D:/Workspace/SpringToolSuiteProjects/ifMobileApiUnitTest/src/main/java/com/isu/ifm/testcase/LoginControllerTest.java:[34,6] cannot find symbol
[ERROR]   symbol:   class Before
[ERROR]   location: class com.isu.ifm.testcase.LoginControllerTest
[ERROR] /D:/Workspace/SpringToolSuiteProjects/ifMobileApiUnitTest/src/main/java/com/isu/ifm/testcase/LoginControllerTest.java:[40,6] cannot find symbol
[ERROR]   symbol:   class Test
[ERROR]   location: class com.isu.ifm.testcase.LoginControllerTest
[ERROR] /D:/Workspace/SpringToolSuiteProjects/ifMobileApiUnitTest/src/main/java/com/isu/ifm/testcase/SalaryControllerTest.java:[25,6] cannot find symbol
[ERROR]   symbol:   class Before
[ERROR]   location: class com.isu.ifm.testcase.SalaryControllerTest
[ERROR] /D:/Workspace/SpringToolSuiteProjects/ifMobileApiUnitTest/src/main/java/com/isu/ifm/testcase/SalaryControllerTest.java:[30,6] cannot find symbol
[ERROR]   symbol:   class Test
[ERROR]   location: class com.isu.ifm.testcase.SalaryControllerTest
[ERROR] /D:/Workspace/SpringToolSuiteProjects/ifMobileApiUnitTest/src/main/java/com/isu/ifm/testcase/EDocumentControllerTest.java:[25,6] cannot find symbol
[ERROR]   symbol:   class Before
[ERROR]   location: class com.isu.ifm.testcase.EDocumentControllerTest
[ERROR] /D:/Workspace/SpringToolSuiteProjects/ifMobileApiUnitTest/src/main/java/com/isu/ifm/testcase/EDocumentControllerTest.java:[30,6] cannot find symbol
[ERROR]   symbol:   class Test
[ERROR]   location: class com.isu.ifm.testcase.EDocumentControllerTest
[ERROR] /D:/Workspace/SpringToolSuiteProjects/ifMobileApiUnitTest/src/main/java/com/isu/ifm/testcase/LoginControllerTest.java:[36,9] cannot find symbol
[ERROR]   symbol:   variable MockitoAnnotations
[ERROR]   location: class com.isu.ifm.testcase.LoginControllerTest
[ERROR] /D:/Workspace/SpringToolSuiteProjects/ifMobileApiUnitTest/src/main/java/com/isu/ifm/testcase/SalaryControllerTest.java:[23,49] cannot find symbol
[ERROR]   symbol:   class SalaryController
[ERROR]   location: class com.isu.ifm.testcase.SalaryControllerTest
[ERROR] /D:/Workspace/SpringToolSuiteProjects/ifMobileApiUnitTest/src/main/java/com/isu/ifm/testcase/EDocumentControllerTest.java:[23,55] cannot find symbol
[ERROR]   symbol:   class EDocumentController
[ERROR]   location: class com.isu.ifm.testcase.EDocumentControllerTest
[ERROR] -> [Help 1]
[ERROR]
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR]
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoFailureException
```

Comment: I suggest you to post the entire pom.xml

Comment: Please try the command line: `mvn clean package` and post the result in the question body.

Comment: First of all, you have duplicate spring-beans dependency. Remove one of them.

Comment: I just made a demo project with your pom, it's working fine (without the system dependencies). Maybe deleting the .m2 directory from your home folder and `mvn clean package` again would help.

Comment: Wow I appreciate it a lot! I will:D

Answer (score 0):

Just changing the version should work but you have to follow the instructions by spring community.

But before that clear the m2 repository and do clean install to download maven dependencies again in case if corrupted jars.

[Upgrading-to-Spring-Framework-4.x](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/wiki/Upgrading-to-Spring-Framework-4.x)

And try to do eclipse clean project and then `Maven > update project` should solve your issue.follow steps given below.

1. Project -> Clean
2. Restart Eclipse
3. Disable then re-enable dependency management (right-click Maven -> Disable Dependency Management then Maven -> Enable Dependency Management
4. Close and Reopen Project
5. Project -> Run as -> Maven Build -> Set goals as `clean install` -> Select options `Update Snapshots` `Debug Output` `Non Recursive` `Resolve Workspace Artifacts` -> Apply and Run
6. Repeat Step 5 after removing dependencies from ~/.m2/repository
7. Check that your Maven settings are configured correctly. If you are behind a proxy you'll need to configure the proxy settings in the global or user settings.

Answer (score 0):

i have also faced the same problem while updating the spring version

i checked your POM.XML File so there is no jackson dependency so add below dependency it works

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
        <version>2.8.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-annotations</artifactId>
        <version>2.8.1</version>
    </dependency>
```

if you not used above dependency version use the latest version of dependency which version you want.